# I was looking at a problem merge two sorted arrays in leetcode

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-sorted-array/

You are given two sorted arrays and their lengths and you need to combine them into a sorted array.

> **Example 1:**
>
> ```
> Input: nums1 = [1,2,3,0,0,0], m = 3, nums2 = [2,5,6], n = 3
> Output: [1,2,2,3,5,6]
> ```
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> ```
> Input: nums1 = [1], m = 1, nums2 = [], n = 0
> Output: [1]
> ```
>
> Explanation: The arrays we are merging are [1] and []. The result of
> the merge is [1].
>
> **Example 3:**
>
> ```
> Input: nums1 = [0], m = 0, nums2 = [1], n = 1
> Output: [1]
> ```

My code:

```
 class Solution:
    def merge(self,a, m, b, n):
        i,j = 0,0
        arr=[]
        while i<m and j<n:
            if a[i]<b[j]:
                arr.append(a[i])
                i+=1
            else:
                arr.append(b[j])
                j+=1
        if m!=i:
            while i!=m:
                arr.append(a[i])
                i+=1
        if n!=j:
            while j!=n:
                arr.append(b[j])
                j+=1
        return arr
```

The problem is I cant get right output and code is working fine in ide-jupyter or vs code but isn't working on leetcode.

Comment: Show the output you get (with the input) as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: What do you mean by *isn't working*? you get wrong output? errors?

Comment: Read the challenge description carefully, especially the last paragraph, which you did not include in your question, and which I suppose you didn't read.

Comment: Thanks for the help @trincot actually I was reading some solutions in the discussion and many solutions were not in nums1.

Comment: Sir, I have clearly mentioned I am getting the wrong answer in leetcode but the code is working fine in IDE.

Comment: Because your IDE doesn't complain if you return a result instead of modifying the input in-place.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the requirements from your link carefully:

```py
"""
Do not return anything, modify nums1 in-place instead.
"""
```

your task is to modify `a`, not return anything

Comment: But still, it is not giving the right answer.

Comment: @VishavSingla Please update your question and show (1) what answer you get (2) what is the specific input for this answer and (3) what would be the correct answer.

Comment: @VishavSingla, that means your correction is not good enough. This answer here answers directly to your question. If you have a new problem after using this answer, then it doesn't belong here. Ask a new question.